# Unable to access ConfigurationManager.AppSettings in a Windows Forms Application

Tags: winforms, application-settings

How can I access `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` in my Windows Forms Application?

The error message reads: The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Add a reference to System.Configuration.dll.

Comment: Duh!.. Not used to winforms development--when doing web applications, everything is included by default.. Or so it seams. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 3):

I've had this experience before where I had to go and add a reference to System.Configuration to be able to use this funcitonality.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your project in the solution explorer, select Add Reference then select the .Net tab (it should be selected by default), and select System.Configuration