# Load a different MyExeName.config XML (Project Settings file) to the default one?

Tags: c#, winforms, configuration, configurationmanager, settings.settings

I see this question asked many times about the ASP.NET style of application settings where the loading is done and then the code contains calls to `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySettingHere"]` ..

..but my WinForms app doesnt use this method. Instead it uses the Project Settings route (i.e. I call `Properties.Settings.Default.MySettingName`  to get my value, and I edit my settings by getting properties on the project and choosing the Settings tab)
App.config as a file is present in the root of the project/solution, but there is also Settings.settings and Settings.Designer.cs and I think these are the ones used and transformed into compiled code that gets the data

Essentially Visual Studio provides a type safe wrapper around the settings load/save/value getting process, and what I'd like to do is supply a path of the settings file to load rather than have it stuck at taking the default MyExeName.config file from the application directory

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something in your question, but you can absolutely use Config Manager in your winforms app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796851/unable-to-access-configurationmanager-appsettings-in-a-windows-forms-application

Comment: As far as having multiple config files, you can have your app.config load as many config files as you want and reference them all through Config Manager.  [This answer shows how to set that up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769373/how-to-read-values-from-multiple-configuration-file-in-c-sharp-within-a-single-p).

Comment: Hi paqgomez.. Thanks for the pointer, but none of my code uses ConfigurationManager directly, it uses Project Settings (which is a visual designer wrapper for CM, i think) in the same way you COULD write all the code to lay out a winforms Form yourself, but you use the visual designer.. This is the same thing, but for settings.

Comment: I certainly know I COULD have used Config Manager, but when I wite a winforms app, and I want a setting, I go to Project menu.. Properties.. Settings tab, "this project does not contain a settings file, click here to create one", so i click there.. Add my first setting. It's like Resources, but for Settings. Once defined I can save the settings and access them by calling MyProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.WindowHeight or whatever, as a type safe property, not ConfigManager.AppSettings["WindowHeight"] which I then have to parse. I want to know how to load another Settings file

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to load custom configuration file from desired location rather than loading the default config, then try this,

> **NOTE** : You can't have more than one App.config in a project.The app will use the config file named YourExcecutable.exe.config which is by
>   default the file App.config. But you can have multipe configuration
>   files and load then as you need using code. But you can't keep all of
>   them loaded at the same time. you can only switch between the files as
>   you need.

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap("path to new file"); 
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
```

`OR`

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", @"Config file path");
```

Comment: Alas, I didn't get any success with either of these methods. If I call AppDomain...SetData(...) and then call MyNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.Reload() it only loads the old values. If I go the System.Configuration.* route, then the configuration variable does have settings in, but not in the form that Proeprties.Settings.Default.NAMED_PROPERTY_HERE uses

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found so far is rather a poor man's solve..

When we use the Settings tab inside a project's properties, the solution will gain a Settings.Settings, Settings.Designer.cs under the project's Properties node and possibly also an app.config in the root of the project. Edits to these files directly seem to be copied/updated /synchronised by VS itself. It also maintains some code in the background to ensure data-typed access to these settings. Likely it's based on Configmanager.AppSetings["propertyName"] but because VS is used to set up the property, and you tell it it's an int (or whatever) then VS can write wrapper code that exposes a namespace/class/member chain of ProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.PROPERTYNAME

Seemingly this code relies on the settingsfile being called THE_EXE_NAME.exe.config and being stored alongside the EXE itself..
..so I just take the the settings file that I want to use, copy it over the top of the one stored on disk, and call ProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.Reload() which does reload the values I want to use out of the new file. I can think of countless reasons why this isn't ideal but it's all I've been able to come up with so far